# Drag and Drop in Nested tree in material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have implemented a nested tree using angular material and I am wondering If nested tree supports drag and drop. I read a article which states below:
***First, understand that the Material tree comes in two flavors: Flat and Nested. They both deliver the same user experience, but in different ways. In order to integrate drag and drop, we need to use the flat tree, because it builds the DOM as single-depth list, using various levels of padding to show nesting.***
Link for the article is as shown https://blog.briebug.com/blog/angular-how-to-implement-drag-and-drop-in-a-material-tree .Does nested tree support drag and drop?Please confirm and show me a example,If it is possible.
My code for nested tree looks like this.

```
 <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild" cdkDrag >
        <div>
            <div class="mat-tree-node" matTreeNodeToggle (contextmenu)="selectednode = node;onRightClick($event);"
            [ngClass]="{ 'background-highlight':selectednode === node  }">
            <mat-icon class="folder-icon-spacing" fontSet="far"
              [fontIcon]="treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'fa-folder-open' : 'fa-folder'">
            </mat-icon>
            <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror chevron-color">
              {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
            </mat-icon>
            <div class="node-format item-font">
              {{node.sectionTitle}}</div>
            <div class="align-setproperties item-font" (click)="showProperties(node)">
              <span *ngIf="node.sectionOrder !== 'Select one';else showprop">
                <span
                  *ngIf="node.randomCount === 0 || node.randomCount === '' || node.randomCount == null || node.hasTitleError ||  node.hasRandomError ; else validCount">
                  <span
                    *ngIf="node.hasTitleError && !node.hasRandomError; else invalid">
                    {{node.sectionOrder}} - {{node.randomCount}} of {{node.totalCount}}
                   </span>
                  <ng-template #invalid>
                    <span>
                      {{node.sectionOrder}} - ? of {{node.totalCount}}
                    </span>
                  </ng-template>
                </span>
                <ng-template #validCount>
                  <span class="validText">{{node.sectionOrder}} - {{node.randomCount}} of {{node.totalCount}}
                  </span>
                </ng-template>
              </span>
              <ng-template #showprop>Set properties</ng-template>
            </div>
            <div style="visibility: hidden; position: fixed" [style.left]="contextMenuPosition.x"
              [style.top]="contextMenuPosition.y" [matMenuTriggerFor]="contextMenu">
            </div>
            <mat-menu #contextMenu="matMenu">
              <button mat-menu-item (click)="add(selectednode)">Add</button>
              <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="selectednode && selectednode.sectionIdent === 0 ? false: true"
                (click)="removeNode(selectednode)">Remove</button>
            </mat-menu>
          
         
          </div>
        </div>

          <div [class.example-tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(node)" role="group">
            <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet>
            </ng-container>
        </div>
        <div *ngFor="let sibling of node.items" style="display:block;min-height: 10px;padding-left: 96px;">
          {{sibling}}
        </div>
      </mat-nested-tree-node>
    </mat-tree>
```